# Pandas missing values using conditions (groupby other columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

df

```
Col A    Col B    Col C 

25       1         2          
NaN      3         1
27       2         3 
29       3         1
```

I want to fill Nan values in col A based on Col C and Col B.

My output df should be like this

```
25       1         2          
29       3         1
27       2         3 
29       3         1
```

I have tried this code `df.groupby(['Col B','Col C']).ffill()`

but didnt worked.Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: You could use `transform`, combined with `fillna` : ``df.assign(**{"Col A" : df["Col A"]. fillna(df.groupby(['Col B', 'Col C'])['Col A'].transform('first'))})`` . transform keeps the same size as the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
df['Col A'] = df["Col A"].fillna(df.groupby(['Col B','Col C'])["Col A"].transform(lambda x: x.mean()))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Col A  Col B  Col C
0   25.0      1      2
1   29.0      3      1
2   27.0      2      3
3   29.0      3      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(['ColB','ColC']).transform('first'),inplace=True)
df
Out[386]: 
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0  25.0     1     2
1  29.0     3     1
2  27.0     2     3
3  29.0     3     1
```